# Postgres Regex Negative Lookahead

Tags: regex, postgresql

Scenario: Match any string that starts with "J01" except the string "J01FA09".

I'm baffled why the following code returns nothing:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE
    '^J01(?!FA09).*' ~ 'J01FA10'
```

when I can see on [regexr.com](https://regex101.com/r/On7Nsx/1) that it's working (I realize there are different flavors of regex and that could be the reason for the site working).

I have confirmed in the [postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-matching.html) that negative look aheads are supported though.

Table 9-15. Regular Expression Constraints

> (?!re)    negative lookahead matches at any point where no substring
>   matching re begins (AREs only). Lookahead constraints cannot contain
>   back references (see Section 9.7.3.3), and all parentheses within them
>   are considered non-capturing.

Comment: Just to be sure do you have any rows in your table? Because it does seem you wrote `SELECT 1 WHERE TRUE`, which should work as long as there are any rows

Comment: @Daniel, please check my answer.

Comment: Right side operand...so obvious.  I realize I don't need regex for my exact example but this is part of a much bigger picture.

Comment: @Xyzk There doesn't need to be a FROM clause or a table for this very simple example to work . It was simply used to test the regex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Match any string that starts with "J01" except the string "J01FA09".

You can do without a regex using

```
WHERE s LIKE 'J01%' AND s != 'J01FA09'
```

Here, `LIKE 'J01%'` requires a string to start with `J01` and then may have any chars after, and `s != 'J01FA09'` will filter out the matches.

If you want to ahieve the same with a regex, use

```
WHERE s ~ '^J01(?!FA09$)'
```

The `^` matches the start of a string, `J01` matches the literal `J01` substring and `(?!FA09$)` asserts that right after `J01` there is no `FA09` followed with the end of string position. IF the `FA09` appears and there is end of string after it, no match will be returned.

See the [online demo](http://rextester.com/ROISZE87157):

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (s)
VALUES
    ('J01NNN'),
    ('J01FFF'),
    ('J01FA09'),
    ('J02FA09')
;
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE s ~ '^J01(?!FA09$)';

SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE s LIKE 'J01%' AND s != 'J01FA09';
```

[image]

Comment: Marking as the answer since you've added the end of string piece '$' that I hadn't seen yet.  My biggest problem was just that my silly test case had the operand sides swapped.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, another improvement is that you actually do not need `.*` at the end as the regex check performed with `~` does not require a full string match (unlike `LIKE` or `SIMILAR TO` patterns that need a whole string match).

Answer (score 3):

RE is a right side operand:

```
SELECT 1
WHERE 'J01FA10' ~ '^J01(?!FA09)';

 ?column? 
----------
        1
(1 row)
```

Comment: However, with this pattern, OP won't achieve the required results.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - I do not know how OP is going to use it, but this works well.

Comment: Really appreciate you pointing out the obvious flaw in my operand sides.  That's what was mostly stumping me on getting this simple look ahead working before I put it into the more complex code.

Comment: I think the original question was only missing the end anchor (`$`) from the negative lookahead.