# Simple Negative Lookahead in Postgres 9.5 Not Working

Tags: regex, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, regex-lookarounds

I'm tryin to match any string containing **STORE** when it's NOT followed by **HOUSE**.  I looked at this answer [Postgres Regex Negative Lookahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43875508/postgres-regex-negative-lookahead/43877731#43877731) but cannot get it to work with my example.

Here is the [sql demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.5&fiddle=553f637a78a148ea5b1162a4b78cc098) and below is my code:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
    (s character varying)
;

INSERT INTO table1
    (s)
VALUES
    ('FROM THE STORE TO THE HOUSE AND'),
    ('FROM THE HOUSE TO THE STORE AND')
;
select * from table1 where s ~ '(STORE)(?!HOUSE)';
```

**UPDATE** Had wrong link for SQL demo - it is fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex matches `STORE` only if it is not immediatly followed by `HOUSE`.

I guess you want:

```
(STORE)((?!HOUSE).)*$
```

This will match `STORE` in the second row of your example.